# Microsoft Excel, adding a specific number to a column

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I'm encountering a basic problem with excel and outlook. Please give it a thought.

I have a number in a cell on an excel sheet i need to add 13 and then drag it down to get 13 added to each of the rest as well.

So for example, on the first cell i have the number 184943 i need to add 13 and get the number 184956 in the second cell below then 184969 in the third and so on...

So is there a formula i can use where i can drag from the first number all the results i need

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have multiple ways to make this work.

The easiest/fastest would be to create the first 2 cells manually, select them and if you put the cursor to the bottom right corner of the selected cells, you will notice that it changes to a `+` sign. Just hold click and drag it down, it will keep adding 13 to the value.

If you insist using a formula, try this:

`=INDIRECT("X" & ROW() - 1)+13`

Where X is the letter of the column you want it to apply.

Comment: yeah that's perfect exacly what i was asking for thanks a lot mate

Answer (score 0):

1. Write somewhere, 13
2. Copy that cell
3. Select all numbers 184943,
   184956....
4. Right click, paste special
5. Select, values and add
6. Press enter